ReactJS - Undesired rerender of parent component when child changes props
In InertiaJs using React, I have a Parent component which displays and animates several Childs (Child0, Child1, Child2 based on a tab variable (0, 1 or 2)
...
export default Parent = ({prop1, prop2, prop3, countries}) => {
    const [tab, setTab] = useState(0);
    ...

    return (
        <>
            {tab === 0 && <Child0 prop0={prop0}/>}
            {tab === 1 && <Child1 prop1={prop1} countries={countries} />}
            {tab === 2 && <Child2 prop2={prop2}/>}
        </>
    );
}

Child components consist of forms that make changes to their respective parent props on save.
One of them, Child1 is internally calling InertiaJS router.reload inside useEffect, to lazy load countries information on a select when it mounts, like this:
useEffect(() => {
    ...
    router.reload({ only: ['countries'] });
}, [])

The problem arises when I hit the Tab 1 button in the UI, because it transitions from Tab 0 (default) to Tab 1 form, but then rapidly transitions back to the Tab 0 form. Parent is rerendered (as its props change because countries are being fetched on Child1mount).
How can I deal with this situation?
Or even better... Is there a better component distribution or technique to avoid this problem?
Thanks in advance.

In this example alone, changing values of prop1/prop2/prop3 would not cause tab to reset to 0. Please provide a [mre].

Edited with better explanation @jtbandes

If Parent is re-rendered, state in Parent should not revert back to default. That was the whole point @jtbandes was making. Reloading the whole application will though. If router.reload() does exactly that, then that is your culprit.

I would suggest extracting the reload feature to a separate component that will preserve application state and not cause them all to be lost.

So you mean if router.reload({ only: ['countries'] }); is removed from your useEffect hook, the action is not happened?

Thanks, @ChukwujiobiCanon, I understand. I will do what you suggest.
